# Is message "the ABI of passing struct with a flexible array member has changed in GCC 4.4" important?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I am wondering if this message from the compiler is something that one should carefully consider.

Let's look at the following code:

```
struct s
{
  int a;
  int b[];
};

void fun(struct s c)
{
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
main.c:7:6: note: the ABI of passing struct with a flexible array member has changed in GCC 4.4
```

My question is: is using such structure in bigger projects safe? What are the possible risks and effects of such structure (besides the compiler message)?

Comment: Are you mixing code built with `gcc 4.4` or later with code built with a pre-`4.4` version of `gcc`?

Comment: Yes. It existed before gcc 4.4. The code was made through a longer period of time. I've just noticed this note recently.

Comment: It's not an error message, it's just warning you that the ABI for a construct you use has changed. In practice this means that you can get bugs if you mix object files and libraries compiled with earlier versions of gcc and your current version of gcc.

Comment: So my understanding is that we can leave such structure, but the whole project has to be compiled with gcc >= 4.4 ? If some parts of the project are compiled with gcc < 4.4 this is a great no no ?

Answer (score -2):

1. With respect to memory every time we are calling this function the structure variable is created so wastage of memory.
2. confirm whether u need struct s c or struct s &c in your project.